# R, Merge data frames by column 0

Tags: r, date, merge

I've got 2 data frames containing timeseries(the time is not coded but there is time variable in column 0).The time variable in column zero doesn't allow to me to merge data frames. 
The data looks like this: TVC1 AND TVC2 (these are only 2 data frames out of 20)

[image]
[image]

How can I create time variable or define column zero as time variable to merge the 20 data frames?
Thanks,

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've tried?

Comment: `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "row.names"),  mget(paste0("TVC", 1:20)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a simple way to convert row names into the 1st column of your data using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can place the datasets in a `list` and then do a `merge` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "row.names"), mget(paste0("TVC", 1:20)))
```